# Form Update Database Model Record's Relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5, octobercms

I want to know how to up date a model's relationship using a frontend form. I looked at the documents and found:

> Alternatively you may set the relationship using the primary key, this
>   is useful when working with HTML forms.

```
// Assign to author with ID of 3
$post->author = 3;

// Assign comments with IDs of 1, 2 and 3
$post->comments = [1, 2, 3];

$post->save();
```

the backend form to update the relationship works fine. This is my code and where I am getting ID as a value but it doesn't seem to affect the relationship field. Help would be great thanks!

```
    $project = new Projects(); 
    $project->name = Input::get('name');
    $project->price = Input::get('price');
    $project->work = Input::get('work');
    $project->client = Input::get('client');
    $project->slug = $slug;
    $project->save();
    Flash::success('Estimate Added!');
    return Redirect::refresh();
```

This is the Pivot Table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('brandon_invoice_ip', function($table)
        {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->integer('invoices_id');
            $table->integer('projects_id');
            $table->primary(['invoices_id','projects_id']);
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('brandon_invoice_ip');
    }
}
```

Here is the model relationship:

```
public $hasOne = [
        'client' => 'Brandon\Invoice\Models\Clients'
    ];
```

This is the front end form: The values are correct according to their ID.

```
<div class="uk-margin uk-first-column">
    <label class="uk-form-label" for="client">Client</label>
    <div class="uk-form-controls">
        <select class="uk-select" name="client">
          <option value="1">Brandon</option>
          <option value="2">Sanitary Ostomy System</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Image of the relationship in the builder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OqpX.png)

Comment: Are you getting client id with `Input::get('client')` ?

Comment: I updated my code and yes I verified that the values for the clients are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add belongsTo relationship instead of hasOne

```
public $belongsTo = [
    'client' => 'Brandon\Invoice\Models\Clients'
];
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I changed it to a $belongsTo and added the client_id field to the table. That worked, I need to review the documentation again to understand relationships completely.

Comment: I am glad that worked and yes I also think you must re-visit relationship workflow to understand it much better. just a request, can you please upvote my answer ?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After you set the client using:

```
$project->client = Input::get('client');
```

You need to save the changes using:

```
$project->save();
```

Assuming your tables and models have been setup correctly, the above should work. If it does not, you need to post the structure of your tables and the rest of your code.

Comment: I updated my code to show most of it now. I do have $project->save(). All the other fields do fill in the table just fine.